# having problem in aligning the character and bone structure for animation

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

This is the image after aligning them together:

[image]

this is what happening every time i set the armature with body with automatic weights, i have cleared the parents and also tried to make body as the bone structure is but still same problem. i will send the file just dm me.

Comment: you can post the file here and add the link to your post instead of asking people to dm you https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Please embed the link in your post.. then folks will be able to check it out for you

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Before parenting the mesh object to the armature object, make sure that both have their transforms applied.

To apply all of their transforms, put both objects at the world origin, feet on the ground, facing -Y. Then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Transforms: All.

This should make the objects' current location/rotation/scale the default ones. When parenting objects to each other, they shouldn't inherit any offset thanks to this.